# Building errors when building VLC media player

Tags: python, media-player, vlc, ninja, protoc

I am trying to build VLC media player on a Mac, but I get the following errors. All of these are installed and on the latest version. Also I tried putting them in the path etc, but nothing has helped

Errors:

```
protoc too old
ninja not found
To-be-built packages:  protoc ninja
(cd ninja; ./configure.py --bootstrap && mv ninja /Users/valcho/Projects/vplayer/vlc/vlc-3.0/extras/tools/build/bin/)
env: python: No such file or directory
make: *** [.buildninja] Error 127
```

I tried reinstalling and upgrading using brew to clear the errors. All were properly installed and upgraded, but errors persist